# How to read .mp3 files in wcf?

Tags: wcf

How to read the .mp3 audio files ?
I wrote the following code.

```
public static byte[] ReadFully(Stream stream)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    int read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    if (read <= 0)
                        return ms.ToArray();
                    ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
            }
```

It accepts .3gp,.caf foramat streams .why it's not taking .mp3 files?
            }

Comment: Have you made sure that you have the relevant MIME type registered in IIS?

Comment: Yes in iis .mp3 mime type is there but it's not accepting that format stream.

Comment: i wrote service for saving audio files given to mobile team .they are successfully saving the .3gp,.caf foramts audio.but .mp3 can't to save waht is the reason?

Comment: i am using same logic for saving video files.But they are not able to save the video files.

Comment: S  Rajesh it is restful service.

Comment: for .mp3 saving files getting html response. .3gp,.caf format files successfully saving .only .mp3 files are not saving .i added mimetypes but there is no use for .mp3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the below code to download a mp3 file from my REST WCF Service:

```
        [WebGet]
        public Stream GetMp3()
        {
            byte[] buffer;
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "audio/mp3";            
            using (FileStream ms = new FileStream(@"C:\Sample.mp3", FileMode.Open))
            {
                int length = (int)ms.Length;
                WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentLength = length;
                buffer = new byte[length];
                int sum = 0;
                int count;
                while ((count = ms.Read(buffer, sum, length - sum)) > 0)
                {
                    sum += count;
                }
                ms.Close();
            }
            return new MemoryStream(buffer);
        }
```

UPDATE: Upload an mp3 file to Restful WCF service

Server side method:

```
        [WebInvoke]
        public string RecieveMp3(Stream mp3Stream)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[5000000];
            using (FileStream ms = new FileStream("C:\\Temp\\Test1.mp3", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {                
                int read = mp3Stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);                
            }
            return "Recieved Mp3 file";
        }
```

NOTE: 
1. Make sure that you have permissions on the folder to write the mp3 file for the user associated with the app pool under which the wcf service is running
2. For testing purpose i have hard coded the byte array size to be a large value.

Client to call the service:

```
        private string UseRestSharpApproachForFiles(string serviceBaseUrl, string resourceUrl, Method method, string filepath)
        {
            var client = new RestClient();
            client.BaseUrl = serviceBaseUrl;            
            var request = new RestRequest(method) { DateFormat = DataFormat.Xml.ToString(), Resource = resourceUrl };
            request.AddFile("stream", filepath);
            var response = client.Execute(request);
            string responseString;
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                responseString = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(response.Content);
            }
            else
            {
                responseString = response.StatusDescription + " --------------------" + HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(response.Content);
            }
            return responseString;
        }
```

Am using the 3rd party dll for invoking the rest service called RestSharp.